# How to create multiple ggboxplots on the same graph using the loop function?

Tags: r, loops, boxplot, ggpubr

TL;DR: Trying to create multiple boxplots using `ggboxplot` in one graph (images attached), using loop function. Currently manually creating codes for each boxplot, then using either `ggarrange()` or `par()` function to plot them together. It works, but looking for a less repetitive way.

I was wondering if it's possible to create multiple `ggboxplot`s using a loop function. I've seen multiple replies/solutions on StackOverflow but none of them quite accurately captured the solution I was looking for (or that it generally was not necessary to use a loop function).

My data looks something like this:

```
# A tibble: 62 x 4
   offer payoff  partner_transfer  round_type
   <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl>         <chr>     
 1    40    126        66           actual    
 2   100    273       273           actual    
 3     0    100        0            actual    
 4   100      6        6            actual    
 5    25     99       24            actual    
 6    80     29        9           practice    
 7   100     45       45           practice    
 8     0    100        0           practice    
 9    25     99       24           practice    
10   100    183       183          practice    
# ... with 52 more rows
```

The output I'm trying to get is this:

[image: boxplots output]

I was able to get that by running multiple codes, and then using `ggarrange()` function to combine them (below):

```
box_offer <- ggboxplot(data = tg_proposer_split, x = "round_type", y = "offer",
                   fill = "round_type",
                   palette = "ucscgb",
                   ylab = "Offer (by A)", xlab = "Round Type",
                   add = "jitter",
                   shape = "round_type")

box_partner_transfer <- ggboxplot(data = tg_proposer_split, x = "round_type", y = "partner_transfer",
                   fill = "round_type",
                   palette = "ucscgb",
                   ylab = "Amount Transferred by Partner (Bot)", xlab = "Round Type",
                   add = "jitter",
                   shape = "round_type")

box_payoff <- ggboxplot(data = tg_proposer_split, x = "round_type", y = "payoff",
                       fill = "round_type",
                       palette = "ucscgb",
                       ylab = "Payoff (for A)", xlab = "Round Type",
                       add = "jitter",
                       shape = "round_type")

ggarrange(box_offer, box_partner_transfer, box_payoff, 
          labels = c("A", "B", "C"),
          ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

Another way that I'm going about this is by using the `par()` function (but to plot means). Image here:

[image: plotmeans sample]

The code I used for this is:

```
par(mfrow = c(2,2))

plot_offer <- plotmeans( offer ~ round_type, data = tg_proposer_split,
          xlab = "Round Type", ylab = "Offer (by A)",
          main="Mean Plot with 95% CI") 

plot_partner_transfer <- plotmeans( partner_transfer ~ round_type, data = tg_proposer_split,
          xlab = "Round Type", ylab = "Amount Transferred by Partner (Bot)",
          main="Mean Plot with 95% CI") 

plot_payoff <- plotmeans( payoff ~ round_type, data = tg_proposer_split,
          xlab = "Round Type", ylab = "Payoff (for A)",
          main="Mean Plot with 95% CI")
```

While using either `ggarrange()` or `par()` gives me exactly what I want, it's a bit too cumbersome, as sometimes I have over 10 columns/variables that I want to create boxplots for. Hence I'm trying to find some luck here if there is a shorter way to get the output I want without being repetitive in my code. I'm not sure if the problem lies in the way I organised my dataset that is making this process difficult but either way, I'm open to different solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Map` to create list of plots and use `ggarrange` to plot it. Pass column names and y-labels separately.

```
library(ggpubr)

cols <- setdiff(names(tg_proposer_split), 'round_type')
y_labels <- c("Offer (by A)", "Amount Transferred by Partner (Bot)", "Payoff (for A)")

Map(function(x, y) {
  ggboxplot(data = tg_proposer_split, x = "round_type", y = x,
            fill = "round_type",
            palette = "ucscgb",
            ylab = y, xlab = "Round Type",
            add = "jitter",
            shape = "round_type")
}, cols, y_labels) -> list_plots

ggarrange(plotlist = list_plots, common.legend = TRUE)
```

[image]

**data**

```
tg_proposer_split <- structure(list(offer = c(40L, 100L,0L,100L, 25L, 80L,100L, 
0L, 25L, 100L), payoff = c(126L, 273L, 100L, 6L, 99L, 29L, 45L, 
100L, 99L, 183L), partner_transfer = c(66L, 273L, 0L, 6L, 24L, 
9L, 45L, 0L, 24L, 183L), round_type = c("actual", "actual", "actual", 
"actual", "actual", "practice", "practice", "practice", "practice", 
"practice")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Ronak - this works perfectly. Is it possible for me to rename the y labels for each boxplot? If so, how should I go about it?

Comment: You can pass them separately as `y_labels`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Another question I have is:
1. I tried to replicate this code when trying to plot "Plot Means" (in second image/second example given) but it doesn't seem to the working. This is my replicated code: 

`par(mfrow = c(2,2))

cols2 <- setdiff(names(tg_recipient_split[26:28]), "round_type")   

lapply(cols, function(x) {
  plotmeans(x ~ round_type, data = tg_recipient_split,
            xlab = "Round Type", ylab = x,
            main = "Mean Plot with 95% CI")
}) -> list_plots2`

Many thanks again!

Comment: I would suggest to ask that as new question and keep this post focused on only one question.