# How to create multiple plots (plot means) on the same graph?

Tags: r, plot

TL;DR: Trying to create multiple plots in one graph (image attached), using loop function. Currently manually creating codes for each boxplot, then using `par()` function to plot them together. It works, but looking for a less repetitive way.

I was wondering if it's possible to create multiple plots; specifically to plot "plot means". You can find the exact output in image form here (the second example on plot means): [How to create multiple ggboxplots on the same graph using the loop function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66271184/how-to-create-multiple-ggboxplots-on-the-same-graph-using-the-loop-function)

My data looks something like this:

```
# A tibble: 62 x 4
   offer payoff  partner_transfer  round_type
   <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl>         <chr>     
 1    40    126        66           actual    
 2   100    273       273           actual    
 3     0    100        0            actual    
 4   100      6        6            actual    
 5    25     99       24            actual    
 6    80     29        9           practice    
 7   100     45       45           practice    
 8     0    100        0           practice    
 9    25     99       24           practice    
10   100    183       183          practice    
# ... with 52 more rows
```

I'm trying to get it to look like this:

![sample plot means][2]

Currently, my code to get this output is:

```
par(mfrow = c(2,2))

plot_offer <- plotmeans( offer ~ round_type, data = tg_proposer_split,
          xlab = "Round Type", ylab = "Offer (by A)",
          main="Mean Plot with 95% CI") 

plot_partner_transfer <- plotmeans( partner_transfer ~ round_type, data = tg_proposer_split,
          xlab = "Round Type", ylab = "Amount Transferred by Partner (Bot)",
          main="Mean Plot with 95% CI") 

plot_payoff <- plotmeans( payoff ~ round_type, data = tg_proposer_split,
          xlab = "Round Type", ylab = "Payoff (for A)",
          main="Mean Plot with 95% CI")
```

Is there a way I can shorten this code?

Biggest apologies, for some reason I'm unable to attach images because I haven't collated enough reputation points so I have no choice but to try it this way. Hope it is still clear.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to simplify the code with `Map`.

1. Define a general purpose function to take care of the plot, `fun_plot`;
2. Get the column names of the y axis variables;
3. Create a vector of y axis labels;
4. Plot in a `Map` loop.

The code becomes

```
fun_plot <- function(ycol, ylab){
  fmla <- paste(ycol, "round_type", sep = "~")
  fmla <- as.formula(fmla)
  plotmeans(fmla, data = tg_proposer_split,
            xlab = "Round Type", ylab = ylab,
            main = "Mean Plot with 95% CI") 
}

y_cols <- names(tg_proposer_split)[which(names(tg_proposer_split) != "round_type")]
y_lab <- c("Offer (by A)", "Amount Transferred by Partner (Bot)", "Payoff (for A)")

old_par <- par(mfrow = c(2,2))
Map(fun_plot, y_cols, y_lab)
par(old_par)
```

[image]

---

### Edit.

Following the error reported in comment, here is a more general function, allowing for `xcol` and the data set to take any values, not just `"round_type"` and `tg_proposer_split`, respectively. This solution now uses `mapply`, not `Map`, in order for those two arguments to be passed in a `MoreArgs` list.

```
fun_plot2 <- function(ycol, ylab, xcol, data){
  fmla <- paste(ycol, xcol, sep = "~")
  fmla <- as.formula(fmla)
  plotmeans(fmla, data = data,
            xlab = "Round Type", ylab = ylab,
            main = "Mean Plot with 95% CI") 
}

old_par <- par(mfrow = c(2,2))
mapply(fun_plot2, y_cols, y_lab, 
       MoreArgs = list(
         xcol = "round_type", 
         data = tg_proposer_split
       )
)
par(old_par)
```

**Data**

```
tg_proposer_split <- read.table(text = "
   offer payoff  partner_transfer  round_type
 1    40    126        66           actual    
 2   100    273       273           actual    
 3     0    100        0            actual    
 4   100      6        6            actual    
 5    25     99       24            actual    
 6    80     29        9           practice    
 7   100     45       45           practice    
 8     0    100        0           practice    
 9    25     99       24           practice    
10   100    183       183          practice    
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi Rui, thanks for your help. I just tried to run it, but it's giving me an error:
`Error in title(...) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'` at the 
`Map(fun_plot, y_cols, y_lab)` line. 

I'm using a slightly different dataset, but the format is exactly the same so there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @JoyceChua Try to see what is passed to the function `fun_plot` by adding two lines at its beginning: `print(ycol); print(ylab)`. Also, is your real data set named `tg_proposer_split`?

Comment: The real data set isn't named tg_proposer_split, but the data used is similar. I was able to edit the code accordingly and make it work, so this is really helpful. Thanks! :)